# Big O of a for loop within a for loop

Tags: c++, big-o

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    for (int j= 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cout << ".":
    }

}
```

I am trying to find the big O of this function. I believe it is O(n*n) but can someone explain to why it is? And what would the worst case be?

Comment: Why do you think it's O(n^2)?

Comment: worst case? The number of iterations is fully determined and is exactly `k*n`, theres no "worst" or "best" case scenario

Comment: How many times does the outer loop iterate? What about the inner loop? Both have a "fixed" boundary, that is, the inner one doesn't have a condition like `j < i`, so the answer is simple.

Answer (score 1):

It's `O(n*k)`. The outer loop runs `k` times, the inner runs `n` times, thus together `k*n` times.